# Sending Screen Image and Showing continuously

Tags: java, image, networking

I am making a project for Controlling a PC from any other PC on a Network.
but when i send the image from server to client, it does not changed, just the first image is displayed.
So i am sending the captured images of server to client using GZIP compression.

Here is the Server's Code:

```
out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
zipout = new GZIPOutputStream(out);
while(true)
{
img = conn.getScreenImg(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
//Here conn is a Object of Robot Class
ImageIO.write(img, "jpeg", zipout);
Thread.sleep(200);
System.out.println("Success");
}
```

Client Code: displaying the Images sent by Server.

```
while(true)
{
try 
{
img = ImageIO.read(zipin);
Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
Thread.sleep(100);
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

I need Help with this. The image doesn't change on client.
and i want to know that if it is good to use GZIP here for compression for images to send over network , will it accelerate the process. or should i use some other method.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are displaying the images on the client doesn't seem right to me. It would be a lot better to write a custom `JPanel` that would override the `paintComponent` method and that would handle the image rendering. Something like below:

```
  class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage image = null;

    private void setImage(BufferedImage img) {
      image = img;
      repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      if (image != null) {
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
      }
    }    
  }
```

Inside your `while` loop you would call the `setImage` method on the panel. The panel in of course previously instantiated and added to a container.

Comment: i tried your solution . but the first image displayed for a while then the blank screen comes up.

Comment: Please check if you are setting real images.

Comment: but on the server side 
"Success" is printed only once and i really dont know why???